# Django self.request unresolved attribute (Login)

Tags: django, django-forms, request, django-class-based-views

I got a little issue with self.request in (Django: V 1.8.4, Python: V 2.7.6) a simple login module. I just started out with Django, so if it comes out to be be dumb-*** question, sorry :)

Anyway I have a login module in CBV's. So my Login view (FormView) which uses the django.contrib.auth.forms AuthenticationForm. When the form is valid, I want to login the user with the django.contrib.auth login method takes the parameter request.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
```

Which results in a PyCharm notice:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'request' for class 'Login'
```

I can't really figure out why there is no request available or where to pass the request to the form_valid method. Can somebody explain why my approach isn't working, and push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.request` is perfectly fine, and your code should work with no problems.

In a dynamic language like Python, an IDE cannot definitively determine what attributes are available on an object, and you should not rely on it.

Comment: Ah I get it. It makes perfect sense now. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens because of inheritance as some Abstract classes may references to attributes not defined in these classes.

As Daniel mentioned it's just okay. You don't need to think much because of this.